# Combinatoric question - $5$ Pencils in $3$ different colors [Probability]

Tags: real-analysis, probability, combinatorics

A player has $5$ pencils: $2$ Red, $2$ Blue, $1$ Green.

He has a $3$ x $3$ table, in which he has to paint every single cell in one color only.

The player pick each time one pencil randomly, and paint $1$ cell, and returns the pencil.

I want to find $\Omega$ for this situation.

We have $5$ pencils, and $9$ cells, so is it $|\Omega|=9^5$?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to keep track of.  If it is just the color of each cell, then it would be $3^9$ as each cell has $3$ color options. If you want to keep track of pencil was used, that's $5^9$.

Comment: Did you want to say $5^9$?

Comment: Yes, $5^9$. Thank you!